# MPI segmentation fault when buffer size is too large

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

I tried to write some hello-world program in MPI:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE (1024 * 1024)


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  float data[BUFFER_SIZE];
  float base_output[BUFFER_SIZE];
  
  printf("Buffer size is %d\n", BUFFER_SIZE);
  printf("Data pointer is %p\n", data);
  printf("Output pointer is %p\n", base_output);

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  MPI_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 26322 RUNNING AT lindeMacBook-Pro.local
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault: 11 (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

Here's how I compile and run the code.

```
mpicc -o test test.c -O3 -march=native -g -Wall
mpiexec -n 4 ./test
```

The BUFFER_SIZE seems to affect the result. When it's smaller, e.g. (1000*1024), the program produces the desired result. But when it's larger than 1024*1024, it will crash.

Comment: Allocate using `malloc` instead or make the variables `static`. See the linked dupe.

Comment: or increase the stack size. `ulimit -s unlimited` can help. btw, that should not be related to MPI ...